# What is the largest integer number base 16 that can be store in a variable of type dword?

Tags: assembly, masm

What's the largest number it can store?

More importantly, could someone explain why dword can't store a larger number?

Answer (score 6):

It has nothing to do with the base used per se.  The largest number a DWORD can store is constrained by the fact that DWORD (at least in typical usage of DWORD, which is a Microsoft typedef) is a 32 bit wide unsigned integer.  That means the largest number it can store is 2^32-1.

- In binary that's `11111111111111111111111111111111`.
- In hex it's `0xFFFFFFFF,` as @GregHewgill said.
- In Decimal that's `4294967295`.
- In octal that's `37777777777`.

Those are the same number just using different bases.  Binary shows what's truly going on at a machine level.  Maximum value of DWORD, which is 32 bits wide, has all 32 bits on.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your `dword` is 32 bits. The largest number that can be stored in 32 bits in binary is all 1s:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

In base 16 (hex), this is

```
0xFFFFFFFF
```

You can't store an integer any larger than this because then you would need 33 bits.