# Printing out DWORD in hex returns 0x7FFFFFFF in win32 c++

Tags: c++, winapi, dword

I'm currently working on win32 application that uses sha1 hash on strings to generate keys for my map. I want to use the hash as `DWORD`, so I can compute some calculations between hashes.

Since sha1 hash reproduces 160-bit hash values, I created a struct with 5 `DWORD` (32-bit * 5 = 160).

```
struct _SHA1_HASH
{
   DWORD dwFirst;
   DWORD dwSecond;
   DWORD dwThird;
   DWORD dwFourth;
   DWORD dwFifth;
}SHA1_HASH;
```

And I have hashed the string and stored into the struct.

```
void GenerateNodeKey()
{
    // SHA-1 Hashing Process
    // ex) strHash = 356A192B7913B04C54574D18C28D46E6395428AB    

    SHA1_HASH key;
    string s_prefix = "0x";
    key.dwFirst = strtol((s_prefix+strHash.substr(0,8)).c_str(), 0, 0); // first 8 bytes
    ...
    ...
    key.dwFifth = strtol((s_prefix+strHash.substr(32,8)).c_str(), 0, 0); // last 8 bytes
}
```

But the problem arose when I try to print the value to check if they are alright.

```
    wcout << hex 
          << "Node ID : " << key.dwFirst << key.dwSecond << key.dwThird << key.dwFourth << key.dwFifth 
          << dec
          << endl;
```

It prints out with no problems if the 8-byte hex value is less than 7FFFFFFF (2,147,483,647). However, when it is larger than the value, it just prints out the max number. I searched online to see if how large can `DWORD` hold, and that was no problem (Related : [What is the largest integer number base 16 that can be store in a variable of type dword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047722/what-is-the-largest-integer-number-base-16-that-can-be-store-in-a-variable-of-ty))

Can somebody help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So… convert to an unsigned integer, which has the full positive range your strings have?  (Never mind why you’re getting a *string*-valued hash, which must have been converted from integers already…)

Comment: `key.dwFirst = std::stoul(strHash.substr(0, 8), nullptr, 16);` . You can use the base argument for stoul or strtoul instead of prepending 0x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strtol` function returns a signed long integer, which on windows has a range of [-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019).

If `strtol` detects that the number generated is out of range, it will return the maximum long value. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol):

> If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return
>   type, a range error occurs (setting errno to ERANGE) and LONG_MAX,
>   LONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX or LLONG_MIN is returned.

Use `std::strtoul` instead.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! That was fast. Any suggestion on the function that I can use to convert the string to  DWORD?

Comment: Nevermind, I used `istringsteam` to solve the problem. Thanks for the help.